# How do I setup Linux running in a VMware Fusion VM so directories created in shared storage have write access?

Tags: linux, vmware-fusion, share, file-permissions

I have Ubuntu (Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS) running in a VMware Fusion VM, and I'm sharing my Mac's home directory using Fusion's sharing feature. I've created a subdirectory in my home directory and used the Finder's Get Info (and "Apply to Enclosed Items") to give read & write access to "Everyone". But when I (or a program) create a sub-subdirectory in Ubuntu, I (in Ubuntu) don't get read access:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 1818155768 302979775  68 2009-10-26 14:20 temp
```

(This is a line from an `ls -l` in my VM, after `mkdir temp`.)

Is it possible to configure the VM (or the Linux guest or the Max OS X host) so directories are created with write access? How?

**Update:** I created a /temp directory on my Mac and shared it in Fusion with read & write permission.  Then I did the following:

```
$ cd /mnt/hgfs/temp/
$ ls
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -l
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 1 1818155768 80 68 2009-10-27 17:21 foo
```

As you can see, `foo` was created in the (Ubuntu) VM, but the VM doesn't have write access.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the uid= option when mounting hgfs - example on the web [here](http://www.gunfist.com/techy/2008/10/vmware-hgfs-permissions/).  You probably want the uid set to whatever your uid in ubuntu is (`id` to find out).

Alternatively if you wanted every folder you made to be mode 777, that's `umask`.  I'm unclear when you talk about the "vm not having access" - the VM has access, but not your account.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the shared folder to "Read & Write" in Fusion's preferences? And you do have VMware tools installed and up to date right?

**EDIT**: After ensuring that the VMware tools are installed properly, try a reboot of the virtual machine to ensure all modules are loaded properly.

If that doesn't work, try creating a new shared folder, maybe on the root of your Mac's hard drive, and see if you can share that Read/Write. This will help determine where the problem is.

**EDIT2**: If you're able to `mkdir foo`, then the VM has access to the shared folder. Can you do the same thing in your home directory?

Comment: I do have it set to "Read & Write".  But I ran into a problem installing tools: http://serverfault.com/questions/78757/

Comment: Ah ha, that's probably what the issue is.

Comment: I'm both skeptical and hopeful.

Comment: Does this work after installing VMware tools?

Comment: No, I'm still having the same problem.  But I'm not sure VMware Tools is properly installed.  See "Update 3" in my question in  serverfault.com/questions/78757.

Comment: See my edits, let me know if they help / what the results are

Comment: I confirmed that VMware Tools is installed, but I'm still having the problem.