# How do I install VMware Tools in an Ubuntu VM running in VMware Fusion?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-fusion, vmware-tools

I have Ubuntu (Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS) running in a VMware Fusion VM, and I believe I've installed VMware Tools.  But how can I confirm that VMware Tools is running correctly?

When I try step 8 of http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws%5Fnewguest%5Ftools%5Flinux.html#wp1127177 (in an xterm) I get:

```
$ su -
Password: 
# vmware-toolbox &
[1] 7791
(vmware-toolbox-gtk:7791): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I wonder if it's also a bad sign that the menu item in Fusion's Virtual Machine menu still reads "Install VMware Tools" rather than "Update VMware Tools".  Or perhaps Fusion can't properly detect whether Tools is running in Ubuntu (and this is not a problem)?

**Update 5:** (1 through 4 are below) I've confirmed that the VMware Tools are running correctly, by running (in an xterm):

```
$ su -
# /etc/init.d/vmware-tools restart
```

...as suggested by [Josh](https://serverfault.com/users/11086/josh).

So at least for an Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS guest and VMware Fusion 2.0.6, the "Install VMware Tools" item in the Virtual Machine menu does not change to "Update VMware Tools" when they're properly installed.

**Update 6:** After reading [Thorbjørn](https://serverfault.com/users/10898/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen)'s comment, I ran:

```
$ sudo -s
# vmware-toolbox
```

...and got:

```
(vmware-toolbox-gtk:8192): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "ubuntulooks",
```

...and a "VMware Tools Properties" dialog box appears.

```
# /etc/init.d/vmware-tools restart
```

...doesn't report any errors.

Copy & paste was working for me previously, but now it's stopped: the clipboard is no longer copied from the guest to the host, nor visa-versa.

---

The following was written before I was able to install VMware Tools:

I have Ubuntu (Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS) running in a VMware Fusion VM, and I'm trying to install VMware Tools.  I'm following the instructions at [`http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html`](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html).

I choose **Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools**, and (after pressing the **Install** button in the confirmation dialog) a "VMware Tools" item appears in Ubuntu's Places menu.  But nothing happens after I select it.  And `ls /media/cdrom0` returns nothing.

**Update:** Responding to [Josh](https://serverfault.com/users/11086/josh)'s suggestions:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
varrun on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,mode=0755)
varlock on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devshm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
lrm on /lib/modules/2.6.24-23-generic/volatile type tmpfs (rw)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
.host:/ on /mnt/hgfs type vmhgfs (rw,ttl=5)
none on /proc/fs/vmblock/mountPoint type vmblock (rw)
/dev/scd0 on /media/cdrom1 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,utf8,user=dspitzer)
tmpfs on /lib/modules/2.6.24-25-generic/volatile type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/dspitzer/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=dspitzer)
```

I tried:

```
$ mount /media/cdrom0
mount: No medium found
```

And seeing "/dev/scd0" above, I tried:

```
$ mount /dev/scd0
mount: block device /dev/scd0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/scd0 already mounted or /media/cdrom1 busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/scd0 is already mounted on /media/cdrom1
```

Which led me to:

```
$ ls -al /media/cdrom1
total 0
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 1996-04-25 00:37  primary volume descriptor for contact information.
```

I'm puzzled.

**Update 2:** [Josh](https://serverfault.com/users/11086/josh)'s suggestion to try:

```
sudo umount /media/cdrom1
sudo mount /media/cdrom1
```

...worked to get the VMware Tools DVD-ROM to mount.  Now I can follow the instructions in http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws%5Fnewguest%5Ftools%5Flinux.html#wp1127177.

**Update 3:** When I try step 8 of http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws%5Fnewguest%5Ftools%5Flinux.html#wp1127177 I get:

```
$ su -
Password: 
# vmware-toolbox &
[1] 6892
(vmware-toolbox-gtk:6892): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Could this be because I'm not actually in an X terminal?  (I'm opening **Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal**.)

I wonder if it's also a bad sign that the menu item in Fusion's Virtual Machine menu still reads "Install VMware Tools" rather than "Update VMware Tools".  Perhaps Fusion can't properly detect whether Tools is running in Ubuntu?

**Update 4:** I ran `xterm` and then the following:

```
$ su -
Password: 
# vmware-toolbox &
[1] 7791
(vmware-toolbox-gtk:7791): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

As you see, I got the same warning.

How can I confirm that VMware Tools is running correctly?

Comment: Yes, vmware-toolbox is for X11

Comment: "su -" forgets the DISPLAY variable which is needed for X11.  Use "sudo -s" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lilott8's answer is correct, here are a few more details:

You want the instructions for the "Tar Installer": http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html#wp1127177

If there's nothing at /media/cdrom0, check to see where the CDROM is mounted by entering into the terminal: `mount`

This will show a list of all mounted filesystems. If the CDROM isn't mounted, try: `mount /media/cdrom0`

**EDIT**: I'm not sure why nothing is showing up in the CDROM. Try (as root) to umount it and remount it?

```
sudo umount /media/cdrom1
sudo mount /media/cdrom1
```

**EDIT2**: vmware-toolbox is only for X11. It adjusts the display size to match the window size and other such things. TO confirm that VMware tools are properly installed and running, restart them:

/etc/init.d/vmware-tools restart

If you are told that they are not (properly) configured and to run `vmware-config-tools.pl`, then they are not properly installed and you should run that script.

Comment: Yours is the only answer addressing the problem I'm having mounting the CD-ROM. Perhaps I should edit my question and change the title to make this more clear.

See my update.

Comment: That's odd. What you want is /media/cdrom1 but it's empty!

Comment: Just grasping at straws, see my edited answer

Comment: See EDIT2 on how to know if vmware tools are running

Answer (score 3):

For Debian/Ubuntu systems I generally prefer to use the open vm tools packages within the repository. It is easier and they work fine.

Install by `sudo apt-get install open-vm-source open-vm-tools`.  Then build the kernel modules by running these two commands.

```
sudo module-assistant prepare open-vm
sudo module-assistant auto-install open-vm
```

Comment: Personally I always use VMware's tools. It's very simple to install them and that way you're sure you're using supported software.

Answer (score 2):

I know on some distros you need to pull the tar.gz file from the cd, un compress it, then run the ./vmware-install.pl.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it

Comment: This is correct, but you might have to do "sudo ./vmware-install.pl" instead. It is recommended that you have gcc installed in your Ubuntu, the VMWare tools will compile a couple of things if you let them.

Comment: Do you mean the physical CD?  Won't I then be installing an out-of-date version of tools?